# SSRS drill through report parameters not refreshing

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS "summary" report that drills through to a "detail" report. When I drill through from the summary report to the detail report I pass the correct value to the detail data set. But then when I try to select a new value from the parameter drop down in the detail report (and click View Report), the detail report does not refresh with the new parameter selection. It just refreshes with the original drill through value. Hope that makes sense. Thank you for any help!

Comment: add more detailed infor with sampel table

Comment: What browser you are using for the report manager?

Comment: Are you testing using SSRS report viewer or through the report server? Sometimes the built in report viewer for SSRS doesnt bother to delete its cache. Try running the report through IE on the report server and see if it makes the update.

Comment: Master Yoda, that worked! I tried it on the report server and the parameters refresh properly. Thank you!